# Converting date strings into date objects using dashes instead of slashes produces inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm trying to convert javascript date strings into date objects. It seems that when I format the strings with slashes, like `2010/05/21`, I get the date object I was expecting, but when I format the string with dashes, like `2010-05-21`, I get a different date object which seems to refer to the previous day.

The following code illustrates my issue:

```
var aDate = new Date('2010-05-21')
console.log(aDate.toDateString())
console.log(aDate.toISOString())

console.log('=-=-=-=-=')

var anotherDate = new Date('2010/05/21')
console.log(anotherDate.toDateString())
console.log(anotherDate.toISOString())
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
2010-05-21T00:00:00.000Z
Thu May 20 2010
=-=-=-=-=
2010-05-21T06:00:00.000Z
Fri May 21 2010
```

It seems like part of the issue might be related to timezones, since getting the ISO string of the date objects shows the date objects to be 6 hours apart from each other, but I have no idea why using dashes instead of slashes would cause that. I'm using Google Chrome on MacOS Sierra, in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2010/05/21` is a non-ISO date format, so support will be browser implementation dependent. Some browsers may reject it, others will accept it but use different time zones. It looks like your browser is parsing `2010/05/21` with your local time zone.

`2010-05-21` is in a simplified [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) format, so ES5+ has specifications for how it must be parsed. In particular, [it must assume the UTC time zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Differences_in_assumed_time_zone).

You can verify that it's using your local time zone by comparing it to how your browser parses an ISO 8601 date and time (which the ES5 specification says [must use the local time zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#ECMAScript_5_ISO-8601_format_support)).

```js
var dateNonISO = new Date('2010/05/21');
var dateLocal = new Date('2010-05-21T00:00:00');
var dateUTC = new Date('2010-05-21');

console.log("Non-ISO:", dateNonISO.toISOString());
console.log("ISO Local:", dateLocal.toISOString());
console.log("ISO UTC:", dateUTC.toISOString());
```