# Mongoose always save wrong Date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have build a model for mongoose and I added a birthdate field to my model like :

```
birthdate: {
type: Date,
required: [true, "Please enter a birthdate"],
lowercase: true,
validate: [isDate, "Please enter a valid birthdate"],
}
```

But when i saved a instance to my database with birthdate field like :

```
"birthdate": "1998/04/01"
```

Mongoose saved it into mongoDB like:

```
1998-03-31T21:00:00.000+00:00
```

Is it a wrong date? And also How to save the correct date to my database?

Comment: when you  console.log new Date() what you see in front of GMT? i wanna to know your timezone

Comment: I want to save it according to UTC @arminyahya

Comment: ok but i need answer of my first question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting date strings into date objects using dashes instead of slashes produces inconsistent results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373384/converting-date-strings-into-date-objects-using-dashes-instead-of-slashes-produc)

Comment: What is your local timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with mongoose. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373384/converting-date-strings-into-date-objects-using-dashes-instead-of-slashes-produc) question has enough information to solve your problem. Try replacing the slashes with hyphens since the format mostly accepted is YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Storing date values as **string** is a design flaw, you should **always** use proper `Date` object. Have a look to proper time zone handling, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/dates.html) about type of mongoose date

change date format and save your data

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var date = "1998/04/01"
var birthdate= moment(date , "YYYY/MM/DD").toDate();
```

object 1 is based on my solution.

object 2 without converting

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff9edc5373396410c493a62"),
    "birthdate" : ISODate("1998-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "date" : ISODate("2021-01-09T17:54:13.685Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff9ee2ce1357a3b546d8573"),
    "birthdate" : ISODate("1998-03-31T19:30:00.000Z"),
    "date" : ISODate("2021-01-09T17:55:56.677Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: but then it return a moment object and mongoose does not support it.

Comment: when you set a field with type: Date, your date should be based on UTC, your input data format is not a UTC format, when you insert data, mongodb do formating, you must change format before inserting, I implemented my code, you should remove `validate: [isDate, "Please enter a valid birthdate"]`, I added my result based on two way

Comment: `validate: [isDate, "Please enter a valid birthdate"]` is a plugin for validate?

Comment: Instead of `.format("YYYY-MM-DD")` better use `.toDate()`